# Is embedded credentials plain text in .twb file?

Tags: tableau-api

I have read https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/security_data.htm, but I am not sure if embedded credentials in .twb file is  plain text or not (encrypted)?

if yes, I guess it's insecurity that embedded credentials doesn't be encrypted. Does it have a way to harden .twb file?

Comment: The credentials aren't stored in the .twb file - they are stored on the Tableau Server.

Comment: Is credentials encrypted in Tableau Server's PostgreSQL?

Comment: I don't know, but I would if it is, I imagine it would have to be decrypted by Tableau before being sent in the connection string to the database. If that is true, then it isn't a 1-way encryption.

Comment: Embedded credentials uploaded to Tableau Server are stored encrypted in PostgreSQL -- last I saw, they used AES with 256 bit keys. You can also configure internal SSL so that communication between Tableau server processes encrypts the credentials in transit.